# How to revert a simple JavaScript loop?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I'm learning basics of JavaScript. I try to code a program that logs the following scheme to the console:

```
*
* *
* * *
* * * *
* * * * *
* * * * *
* * * *
* * *
* *
*
```

I managed to get first half of the task by the code:

```
 var x = 5;
    var line;

    for(var i = 0; i<x; i=i+1){
        line = "";
        for(var j=0; j<x; j=j+1){
            if(j <= i){
                line = line + " * ";
            }
        }
    console.log(line);
    }
```

So it looks like:

```
*
* *
* * *
* * * *
* * * * *
```

Could anybody give me a hint how to get the secod part of the scheme? I'd like to use another loop like the one I have but to revert it's action so that there would be less and less stars in each line.

Comment: Make a second loop with descending values (from 5 to 0)

Comment: Your problem doesn't lie in looping technique, rather you've to handle `line` differently. Instead of setting `line` to an empty string, you need to set it something like `* * * *`, and then remove one star on each round. It doesn't matter, if `i` is increased or decreased in the loop, as long as the loop just stops after a correct count of rounds.

Comment: Why reverse the loop? You can simply build the second part while building the first: https://jsfiddle.net/sdgtpkhL/

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Many solutions are possible but the simplest,  like you suggest, is **reverting the loop**; this is what loop statement should look like:

```
 for(var i = x-1 ; i>=0 ; i--)
```

---

Basically you have to change the for-loop conditions that will go backwards starting from the max-value , this is the first statement part and is called `initializer` ;

the loop must stop/break at `0` , second part of statement called `test` (until the loop satisfies this condition it will go on in next iteration );

the last part of statement is the `iteration update` (how the state should change in next loop);

---

that said changing the statement you should be able to keep your body  unchanged :

```js
var x = 5;
for (var i = x - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  line = "";
  for (var j = 0; j < x; j = j + 1) {
    if (j <= i) {
      line = line + " * ";
    }
  }
  console.log(line);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hints: You need to decrement i and j in the for loop and turn-around the `<`. instead of starting `var i = 0` start at the end with 5.

Comment: Hmmm...I don't think you need to decrement  `j` with this approach, at least not in the code I tried. (Granted, since we're just throwing hints around, our implementations may vary.)

Answer (score 1):

## spoiler:

What about just using a while loop?

```
var count = 0,
    i = 1,
    addition = 1,
    str = null;
while (i) {
    str = new Array(i+1).join('*');
    console.log(str);
    if (i === 5) {
        console.log(str);
        addition = -1;
    }
    i += addition;
}
```

Comment: "Then you won't need to nest multiple loops into eachother". uhhh...You nested a for loop into your while loop? EDIT: Grr, sneaky edits...

Comment: Hence I removed that part since I was trying to remove the inner loop, but didn't find a decent solution without using future tech like string cloning.

Comment: Voila, I cheated and looked up a way to create the string without explicit looping inside the while. Anything else?

Comment: @GlenKeane I wouldn't worry so much about the `n` loops if their avoidance disrupts the readability.

Answer (score 1):

With two for loops **after another**. The first one **adds** stars and the second one **removes** stars:

```
var line = "";
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i += 1) {
    line += "*";
    console.log(line);
}
for(var j = 5; j > 0; j -= 1) {
    line = line.replace(line[j], "");
    console.log(line);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can, as one possible solution, put another `if` clause inside of your loop (read carefully):

> If the line index reached half of the pyramid (maximum line length), start printing `maximumLineLength * 2 - index - 1` instead.

This will essentially change the behaviour of the loop *after the half is reached*, so that the number of starts *will start to decrease instead of increasing*.

---

Another solution, if you're keeping the number of stars in the string, would be to add them until `maxLineLength` is reached, and then subtract them until you go back to 0 (you can use a boolean flag for that).

*I'm not posting actual code to avoid spoiling the solution.*

Answer (score 0):

It's anti-pattern; why would you want this?

Nevertheless - accumulative variable:

```js
var x = 5,
    y,
    line,
    result = [];

while (x--) {
    y = 5 - x;
    line = '';

    while (y--) {
        line = line + '*';
    }

    result.push(line);
}

document.write(result.join('<br>'));
document.write('<br>');
document.write(result.reverse().join('<br>'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution with the conditionals and the one with the two loops are the ones you should use but you *can* compute the number of asterisks with a bit of modular arithmetic directly:

```
var x = 5;
var line;
for(var i = 1;i < x * 2;i++){
  line = '';
  for(var j = 0;j < Math.abs( (i+3) % 8 - 4) + 1;j++){
    line = line + ' * ';
  }
  console.log(line);
}
```

I used a trick that will most probably be seen here as a little bit dirty but it works. The sequence I use here is 1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2 and to get the last 1 I just run it one more time.

In general:
To get a sequence from 1 to x and back to 1 again (with x > 1) run the outer loop x*2 times with `Math.abs( (i+(x - 2)) % (2*x - 2) - (x - 1)) + 1` as the upper limit for the inner loop with i going from 1 to 2x-1.

Proof is left as an exercise for the student.